# SQLite in Flex Help

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, components, rendering

I am trying to get anytihng from my SQLite to render in Flex, and I can't figure out how to display any data, even text, in Flex. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.data.SQLConnection;
        import flash.data.SQLResult;
        import flash.data.SQLStatement;
        import flash.filesystem.File;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var conn:SQLConnection;
        private var createStmt:SQLStatement;
        private var selectStmt:SQLStatement;
        [bindable] public var dataField:ArrayCollection;
        [bindable] private var row:Object;
        [bindable] private var pngIndex:int; 
        [bindable] public  var pngTitle:String; 
        [bindable] private var pngByteArray:ByteArray; 
        [Bindable] private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        private function init():void
        {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener (SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.addEventListener (SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

            var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/NM.sqlite");
            conn.openAsync(dbFile);
        }

        private function openSuccess(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);

            getData();
        }


        private function getData():void
        {
            //status = "Loading data";

            selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
            selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "SELECT Title FROM Data WHERE 'Index' = 0";
            selectStmt.text = sql;

            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

            selectStmt.execute();
        }

        private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            //status = "Data loaded";

            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

            [bindable] var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult(); 
            dataField = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
            dp = ArrayCollection(dataField);

            if (dataField != null) {
                pngIndex = result.data.Index;
                pngTitle = result.data.Title;
                pngByteArray = result.data.Picture; 

                /* Pic.source = pngByteArray; */

            }

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List x="31" y="44" width="511" height="415" dataProvider="{dp}"></s:List>
```

I've tried a number of different components, and I can't seem to get the data to bind properly (although this code finally doesn't have the dreaded "Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to... " message, or the other dreaded "Property undefined" message).

Please help!

Comment: Try binding `dataField` into your `List`'s `dataProvider` instead of `dp`.

Comment: I get the "data binding will not be able to detect assignments to 'dataField'" error when I try that. 
Another common favourite is 1067: Implicit coercions. Argh.

Comment: all instances of `[bindable]` need to be `[Bindable]`.

Comment: Tried it and nothing..............

Any ideas of different components to try attributing? I think I tried altering the SELECT statement to a call a single string value and all that displayed was {dataField}.

Comment: Ok, the metadata must be written `[Bindable]` else it won't function properly so that needs to stay that way.  Next thing to look at: is your query actually returning data?  Set a breakpoint on this line ` dataField = new ArrayCollection(result.data);` and use Flash Builder to see if there is actually any data in `result.data`.  You should also remove the `[bindable]` metadata from `result`.

Comment: Right, when I changed the bindables to upper-case I got the error on result right away.

In the debug view, I don't have any variables in the view, but there aren't any errors either - I previously was using an incorrect SELECT statement and I was receiving errors then.

Comment: If I use an improper component, I'll get a message telling me that the component can't read an array.

Comment: I feel like we're drifting into long discussion here and it's Friday evening so I'll drop a few ideas for you to consider.  One: get [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58) and test your queries to ensure you are getting results.  Two: test that `dataField.length > 0` after you put your results in it.  Three: `if dataField.length == 0` try setting `dataField = new ArrayCollection(["No results"]);` and see if anything shows up in your list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, input and ideas. I'll try them out.

Comment: Yep, wasn't reading SQLite database... not returning any values from it... Don't know why - It was prepopulated in SQLite Manager, perhaps I'll try Lita?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob, have you tried debugging at all?  Is your DB even opening?

Comment: Yeah, the db wasn't opening but it's all sorted now. I had to initialize the original method to call everything - I tried to answer the question to make that known, but I don't have the "reputation" to do that - which would have saved you the grief of writing your answer below. I'll mark it correct anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.data.SQLConnection;
        import flash.data.SQLResult;
        import flash.data.SQLStatement;
        import flash.filesystem.File;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var conn:SQLConnection;

        private function init():void
        {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);
            var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/NM.sqlite");
            conn.openAsync(dbFile);
        }

        private function openSuccess(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);
            getData();
        }

        private function getData():void
        {
            var select:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            select.sqlConnection = conn;
            select.text = "SELECT Title FROM Data WHERE 'Index' = 0";
            select.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            select.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
            select.execute();
        }

        private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var result:SQLResult = event.currentTarget.getResult(); 
            if(result.data)
            {
                list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List id="list" x="31" y="44" width="511" height="415" labelField="Title" />
```

I also recommend you read up more on how Flex works with lists and item renderers.  There was a lot of problems with this code (ie. `result.data.Index;` is wrong since `data` is an array).  From what I can gather, you'll want a custom item renderer.  Furthermore, I don't recommend you use Binding if you don't need it (as with this example altogether) since it incurs extra resources.

Comment: Yeah, the code I posted was just a worksheet - I know result.data[0].Index is the proper syntax for what I wanted, but I was pulling my hair out because everything looked fine, and sure enough was, after I found the method I was missing in the first place. 

And I hear you about the binding.